# Using Google Oauth in FeathersJs with an existing access token

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, feathersjs

How do I use the Google Oauth in featherjs with an existing access token? The [docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth.html#flow) do not give an example on this. The only example is through the browser as shown [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/google.html#using-the-data-returned-from-the-google-app-through-a-custom-oauth-strategy).

When going through the browser, `http://localhost:3030/oauth/google` works ok. I can successfully add the user to my DB. Here is my code:

```
const { LocalStrategy } = require("@feathersjs/authentication-local");
const { expressOauth } = require("@feathersjs/authentication-oauth");
const { OAuthStrategy } = require("@feathersjs/authentication-oauth");
var uniqid = require("uniqid");
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');        

class GoogleStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {
  async getEntityData(profile) {
    const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile);
    console.log({ profile });

    return {
      ...baseData,
      profilePicture: profile.picture,
      email: profile.email,
      password: uniqid.time(),
    };
  }
}

module.exports = (app) => {
const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);        
authentication.register("local", new LocalStrategy());
authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
authentication.register("google", new GoogleStrategy());

  app.use("/authentication", authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

However if I try using an access token,like so

```
POST http://localhost:3030/authentication
data: {
    "strategy": "google",
    "accessToken": "ya29.A0ARrdaM_UJa6idfZr-4taqwkJ6qGBV1Dp9wbxF-wsult8dNPaVNCVg6Fndmrqv7BhRSwxa5gAKllPvbKtsjyxS39WdmWmqkmE42HOsVZaJWHVEttxbebel3zdpD5BSxWtRiG7NuZLNVedMUaK5AdgIRrJk1u"
}
```

I do not get the google profile, no user is added to my DB and  I get this error:

```
{
  "name": "GeneralError",
  "message": "401 Unauthorized",
  "code": 500,
  "className": "general-error",
  "data": {},
  "errors": {}
}
```

I have added `"google"` to my list of `authStrategies` in `default.json`

So my question is what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. Thought I might share. Add this to authentication.js

```
 //add this method
 async getProfile(authResult) {
    const accessToken = authResult.accessToken;

    const { data } = await axios
      .get(
        `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=${accessToken}`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("autherr", error));

    return data;
}
```